# Weak Topology and normed vector space weak topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Given a topological space $X$ and a set of function $\{f_\alpha :X\to Y_\alpha:\alpha \in A\}$. The weak topology generated by $\{f_\alpha\}$ is the unique weakest topology that makes all function $f_\alpha$ continuous.

> Given a normed vector space $X$, the weak topology generated by $X^*$ is known as the weak topology on $X$.

I'm reading the two definitions above, and I don't really get what does it mean for a topology to be generated by the dual space of $X$. Since by definition all $f\in X^*$ is continuous under the norm metric.

Comment: yes, but we want the weakest topology which makes all these maps continuous. You first start with norm-continuous linear functionals, to get $X^*$. Now, forget about the norm. YOu have a collection of maps $X^*$ defined on $X$. Use this family of maps to get the weak topology on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The norm topology is just one topology under which every element of $X^{*}$ is continuous. But it is not always the weakest topology with this property. The weakest one is called the weak topology on $X$.

[ In finite dimensionl spaces the weak topology does coincide with then norm topology].

Answer (score 1):

You're right, all $f\in X^*$ are continuous for the topology induced in $X$ by the norm. But this topology is NOT necessarily the weakest with this property. This is when the weak-topology in $X$ enters the scene.

As an extra, it would be instructive for you to prove the following: for a normed space of finite dimension, the norm-topology and the weak-topology are indeed the same (and in fact, this property holds only for finite-dimensional spaces; that is, in the infite-dimensional case, the weak-topology is strictly weaker than the norm topology).